# Git difference between @{upstream} and @{push}

Tags: git

Running this command shows both `@{upstream}` and `@{push}` references for all the branches in the local repository:

```sh
git branch --format '%(refname:short) [%(upstream:short)] [%(push:short)]'
```

I noticed that some of my branches have both `@{upstream}` and `@{push}` set, some only have `@{upstream}`, and some only have `@{push}`.

`@{upstream}` matches the value of `git config branch.<branch>.remote` + `git config branch.<branch>.merge`, and running `git branch --set-upstream-to=[remote/]other_branch` updates it.

`@{push}` also includes the value of `git config branch.<branch>.remote`, if present, but I couldn't find a way to update the branch part.

Knowing that there's a single remote for both `@{upstream}` and `@{push}`, `@{push}` doesn't seem very useful, still I'm curious what its purpose is and how it can be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@{push}` is meaningful in what Git calls *triangular workflows*.

Suppose you have a repository with one upstream named `fred` that is a *read-only* place where you get updates from some group, and a second upstream named `wilma` that is a *writable* place where you can send a proposed update for that branch.  Someone else will look at commits you send to `wilma`, and if they are approved, put them into `fred`.

In other words, the triangle looks like this:

```
fred     wilma
  *<------*
   \     ^
    \   /
     v /
      *
     you
```

You therefore wish to set up your branch `feature` to *receive* from `fred` but *send* to `wilma`.  To do this, configure `feature` to have `fred/feature` as its upstream, and `wilma/feature` as its push target.  `feature@{push}` now refers to `wilma/feature` while `feature@{upstream}` refers to `fred/feature`.

[Notes from @DanBerindei; see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135912/git-difference-between-upstream-and-push/63144528#comment112317054_63144528)]: You can configure the push remote for all branches:

```
git config remote.pushDefault wilma
```

or only for the `feature` branch:

```
git config branch.feature.pushRemote wilma
```

You can not change the push branch name. You should instead use the `current` push strategy, so that the push branch name is the same as the local branch name (instead of the upstream branch name).

```
git config push.default current
```

Note: The `@{push}` suffix only works after the first push, even though the manual says it's "where we would push to".

Comment: that sounds like it would work great my situation, but it's at odds with the fact that both `@{push}` and `@{upstream}` seem to use the same remote. Do you know how I could change `@{push}` to point to a different repository? Or even to a different branch at this point, because I don't know how to change it at all.

Comment: There is  sample setup in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions): search for the word "triangular". See also `remote.pushDefault` in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: Thanks @torek, a triangular workflow is exactly what I have, and I suspect many (if not most) Git users have the same workflow. The upstream source doesn't have to bee read-only, either: even though I can push directly to `upstream/master`, I push to a task branch in my own fork instead and open a pull request from that task branch.